# q-select jump on select

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

When an option is selected with these q-select inputs, the input field jumps out of the margin a bit. How do I fix this so that when an option is selected, there is not a jump that puts the field out of alignment with the aligned horizontal field?

https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/RwENYEX

```
<div id="q-app">
 <div style="width: 100%">
   <q-select square class="input- 
   left" filled v-model="selectModel" :options="['A', 'B', 
   'C']" :multiple="true" label="Enter"
   />
   </q-select>
  <q-select class="input-right" square
   filled v-model="select"
   :options="['A', 'B', 'C']"
    :multiple="true" label="Enter" >
  </q-select>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 100%"><q-select square class="input- 
 left" filled v-model="selectModel" :options="['A', 'B', 
 'C']" :multiple="true" label="Enter"
  />
 </q-select>
 <q-select class="input-right" square
   filled v-model="select"
  :options="['A', 'B', 'C']"
   :multiple="true" label="Enter" ></q-select></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'display: flex;' to the two containers around the selects to fix the jumping.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
```

->

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex">
```